# Unable to open a URL in browser using Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, url, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to open a URL using Firebase Cloud Messaging but it's not working. There are many old questions that are related to this topic asked previously here but non of them working in the current scenario. Maybe some things have changed or could be something wrong in my code. So here's my code.

```html
    public void openLink(String title, String url, String message){
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "MyNotification")
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManagerCompat managerCompat =  NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        managerCompat.notify(999, builder.build());
    }
```

And `onMessageReceived` I am calling it like this.

```html
        openLink(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),remoteMessage.getData().get("url"), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
```

But instead of opening URL in a browser on click notification is opening my app. So is there something wrong with code or method of opening URLs have changed?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to send push notification.

1- go to firebase console > cloud messaging > new message, and send a notification
the problem is it'll be shown by android OSand you have no control on it

2- use messaging api and send a json 
in this case you should get rid of "notification" part in json and send all in data.The hardest part is you should handle showing the message.

if you add "notification" in json, Android OS itself will be in charge if showing and handling the message. By removing that you're on your own to handle it

[image]

Comment: I know that, my issue is my app is not opening the link in browser. Notifications are working fine I am receving them in app also the data and url but unable to open that link in a browser

Comment: You can use Intent to do it.                                                                                                  val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(link))
                context.startActivity(intent)

Comment: That's what I was doing, as mentioned in question